# Real life applications of distributions through models or simulations

Tags: harmonic-analysis, special-functions, schwartz-distributions, mathematical-modeling, simulation

What are the areas we can apply distributions in classical harmonic analysis? I don't mean probability distributions but distributions that are continuous linear functionals on the space of test functions. If I wish to venture into research about its applications through mathematical simulations or models or other things,what are the suggestions and helps do you have for me?

Comment: Fourier analysis of a constant signal gives you the Dirac delta function, is that a "real life" application?

Comment: Green functions?